# How to fix multipart/form-data MediaType not being set with Jackson Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson2, fasterxml

I'm trying to send a Product and product images from Angular 7 frontend to a SpringMVC backend.
To add support for Multipart files I've added this bean inside my AppConfig.

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Since I want to receive the Product object separately inside the controller I'm using @RequestPart to fetch both separately like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addProduct(@Valid @RequestPart Product product, @RequestPart MultipartFile[] images, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest 
}
```

On the frontend I'm adding the image to FormData like this:

```
let formData = new FormData();

formData.append('product', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.product)],{ type: "application/json" }));
// I iterate and append all the images like this
formData.append('image[]', this.images, this.images.name);

this.http.post(this.appService.getApiUrl() + "api/product/save/", product);
```

The problem is that whenever I submit the form, I get this exception as a response: **HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type**.
I tried debugging this issue by setting breakpoints inside **CommonsMultipartResolver** class and after tracing the request through the code I've found that when the **getSupportedMediaTypes()** is called it returns only two media types:

1. application/json
2. application/*+json

Inside the following method in **AbstractHttpMessageConverter**:

```
protected boolean canRead(@Nullable MediaType mediaType) {
    if (mediaType == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Iterator var2 = this.getSupportedMediaTypes().iterator();

        MediaType supportedMediaType;
        do {
            if (!var2.hasNext()) {
                return false;
            }

            supportedMediaType = (MediaType)var2.next();
        } while(!supportedMediaType.includes(mediaType));
            return true;
    }
}
```

Finding this I tried adding `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` like this inside AppConfig:

```
@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    for (HttpMessageConverter converter : converters) {
        if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            List<MediaType> types = new ArrayList<>();
            types.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            types.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
            types.add(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).setSupportedMediaTypes(types);

            Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();
       hibernate5Module.disable(Hibernate5Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);

            ObjectMapper mapper = ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);
        }
    }
}
```

But it still wouldn't work. When the app starts up, I do see the constructor of **AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter** being called with my *MediaTypes* but they get overwritten by more calls to the same constructor after it.
Is there any way I can get the MediaType to persist? I might be looking in the wrong direction so any insight will be helpful.

Comment: Try renaming `formData.append('image[]', ...` to `formData.append('images',...` in your JS code to match the signature of your Spring MVC endpoint. I would also switch the variables `product` and `images` in your Java code to make sure that `@Valid @RequestPart Product product` is directly followed by `BindingResult`.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it. It still doesn't work. As I said, the problem is with the MediaType not being found, it only supports application/json and application/+json but not multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to give input data supported at server end. Since you are sending File, means server is consuming the Multipart Data.
For multipart we need to set **consumes = "multipart/form-data"**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity addProduct(@Valid @RequestPart Product product, @RequestPart MultipartFile[] images, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest 
}
```

**2) Since form is sending multipart data we need to set content-type at front end too in http header in post call.**
content-type: multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson library is required on the classpath. Spring does not declare this by default. Make sure that at least `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` is available in the classpath of the Spring MVC application. Example for Apache Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

Example for the `jackson.version` value: 2.9.0

Comment: Hi. I already have it on my classpath. I'm using 2.9.8 version.