# Spring Boot Error while making Post Request receiving unsupported Media Type 415 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

USER CONTROLLER

```
package com.example.fwitterbackend;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.StreamingHttpOutputMessage.Body;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> getAllPosts() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(userService.allPosts(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

             
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Users>> getSinglePost(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Optional<Users>>(userService.singlePost(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Users>> findPostsByUserId(@PathVariable String userId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Users>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }



    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Users>(userService.createUser(null, payload.get("email"), payload.get("firstName"),payload.get("lastName"), payload.get("password"),payload.get("picturePath"), payload.get("occupation"),payload.get("location")), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
 

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> register(@ModelAttribute ObjectId id, User user) {
      try {
        // String firstName = user.getFullName();
        // String lastName = user.getName();
        // String email = ((Users) user).getEmail();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        // String picturePath = ((Users) user).getPicturePath();
        // List<String> friends = ((Object) user).getFriends();
        String location = ((Users) user).getLocation();
        String occupation = ((Users) user).getOccupation();
  
        // String salt = ( (Object) new BCryptPasswordEncoder()).generateSalt(10);
        String passwordHash = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);
  
        Users newUser = new Users();
  
        Users savedUser = userRepository.save(newUser);
  
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
    }
 
}
```

USER SERVICE

```
package com.example.fwitterbackend;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
   
    public List<Users> allPosts() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    
    public Optional<Users> singlePost(ObjectId id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }
    

    
    public List<Users> findPostsByUserId(ObjectId userId) {
        return userRepository.findPostsByUserId(userId);
    }


    public Users createUser(ObjectId id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, String picturePath, String occupation, String location) {
        Users user = userRepository.insert(new Users(id, firstName, lastName, email, password, picturePath, occupation, location ));

        mongoTemplate.update(User.class)
            .matching(Criteria.where("id").is(id))
            .apply(new Update().push("firstName").value(firstName).push("lastName").value(lastName).push("password").value(password).push("picturePath").value(picturePath).push("occupation").value(occupation).push("email").value(email).push("location").value(location))
            // .apply(new Update().push("lastName").value(lastName))
            // .apply(new Update().push("password").value(password))

            .first();

        return user;
    }


    

    
}
```

REACT COMPONENT FORM

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  TextField,
  useMediaQuery,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from "@mui/material";
import EditOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/EditOutlined";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setLogin } from "state";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import FlexBetween from "components/FlexBetween";

const registerSchema = yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required("required"),
  lastName: yup.string().required("required"),
  email: yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
  password: yup.string().required("required"),
  location: yup.string().required("required"),
  occupation: yup.string().required("required"),
  picture: yup.string().required("required"),
});

const loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
  password: yup.string().required("required"),
});

const initialValuesRegister = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  location: "",
  occupation: "",
  picture: "",
};

const initialValuesLogin = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};

const Form = () => {
  const [pageType, setPageType] = useState("login");
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const isNonMobile = useMediaQuery("(min-width:600px)");
  const isLogin = pageType === "login";
  const isRegister = pageType === "register";

  const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    // this allows us to send form info with image
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value in values) {
      formData.append(value, values[value]);
    }
    formData.append("picturePath", values.picture.name);

    const savedUserResponse = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/create",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();

    if (savedUser) {
      setPageType("login");
    }
  };

  const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    });
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
    if (loggedIn) {
      dispatch(
        setLogin({
          user: loggedIn.user,
          token: loggedIn.token,
        })
      );
      navigate("/home");
    }
  };

  const handleFormSubmit = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    if (isLogin) await login(values, onSubmitProps);
    if (isRegister) await register(values, onSubmitProps);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      initialValues={isLogin ? initialValuesLogin : initialValuesRegister}
      validationSchema={isLogin ? loginSchema : registerSchema}
    >
      {({
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleBlur,
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        setFieldValue,
        resetForm,
      }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Box
            display="grid"
            gap="30px"
            gridTemplateColumns="repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr))"
            sx={{
              "& > div": { gridColumn: isNonMobile ? undefined : "span 4" },
            }}
          >
            {isRegister && (
              <>
                <TextField
                  label="First Name"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.firstName}
                  name="firstName"
                  error={
                    Boolean(touched.firstName) && Boolean(errors.firstName)
                  }
                  helperText={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Last Name"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.lastName}
                  name="lastName"
                  error={Boolean(touched.lastName) && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
                  helperText={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: "span 2" }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Location"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.location}
                  name="location"
                  error={Boolean(touched.location) && Boolean(errors.location)}
                  helperText={touched.location && errors.location}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                />
                <TextField
                  label="Occupation"
                  onBlur={handleBlur}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={values.occupation}
                  name="occupation"
                  error={
                    Boolean(touched.occupation) && Boolean(errors.occupation)
                  }
                  helperText={touched.occupation && errors.occupation}
                  sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
                />
                <Box
                  gridColumn="span 4"
                  border={`1px solid ${palette.neutral.medium}`}
                  borderRadius="5px"
                  p="1rem"
                >
                  <Dropzone
                    acceptedFiles=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
                    multiple={false}
                    onDrop={(acceptedFiles) =>
                      setFieldValue("picture", acceptedFiles[0])
                    }
                  >
                    {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                      <Box
                        {...getRootProps()}
                        border={`2px dashed ${palette.primary.main}`}
                        p="1rem"
                        sx={{ "&:hover": { cursor: "pointer" } }}
                      >
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        {!values.picture ? (
                          <p>Add Picture Here</p>
                        ) : (
                          <FlexBetween>
                            <Typography>{values.picture.name}</Typography>
                            <EditOutlinedIcon />
                          </FlexBetween>
                        )}
                      </Box>
                    )}
                  </Dropzone>
                </Box>
              </>
            )}

            <TextField
              label="Email"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.email}
              name="email"
              error={Boolean(touched.email) && Boolean(errors.email)}
              helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
            <TextField
              label="Password"
              type="password"
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={values.password}
              name="password"
              error={Boolean(touched.password) && Boolean(errors.password)}
              helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
              sx={{ gridColumn: "span 4" }}
            />
          </Box>

          {/* BUTTONS */}
          <Box>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              type="submit"
              sx={{
                m: "2rem 0",
                p: "1rem",
                backgroundColor: palette.primary.main,
                color: palette.background.alt,
                "&:hover": { color: palette.primary.main },
              }}
            >
              {isLogin ? "LOGIN" : "REGISTER"}
            </Button>
            <Typography
              onClick={() => {
                setPageType(isLogin ? "register" : "login");
                resetForm();
              }}
              sx={{
                textDecoration: "underline",
                color: palette.primary.main,
                "&:hover": {
                  cursor: "pointer",
                  color: palette.primary.light,
                },
              }}
            >
              {isLogin
                ? "Don't have an account? Sign Up here."
                : "Already have an account? Login here."}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

AT FIRST THE POST REQUEST WAS GIVING ME A CORS ERRORS AND 403 & NOW IT IS GIVING CORS ERRORS AND 415

THINGS I HAVE TRIED

- ADDING NO CORS MODE IN HEADERS
- Changing RequestBody to ModelAttribute

I would really appreciate any type of help or feedback since this taking such a long time to resolve

Answer (score 0):

A 415 means the content-type being sent by the page does not match that being expected by the controller.

The data being submitted is a FormData but the receiving controller method api/v1/users/create - createUser is expecting json (the default when `consumes` is not set).

Try:

```
@PostMapping(
  path = "/create",
  consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Users> createUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
```

Or

```
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
```

The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379499/how-to-fix-multipart-form-data-mediatype-not-being-set-with-jackson-spring-mvc) should be also helpful.